# Two problems with Shiny Modules

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive

Here is a minimum example.  I am trying to modularize an existing app to separate different analysis problems.  Each problem is intended to have a sidebar panel for inputs and a main panel for outputs. I am having two problems with setting  up the siderbar panel for inputs.  I will have two buttons that are exchanged after the first is selected.  This action is in the module server code that requires reading in the selected analysis (tab label in the navbar) and then acting on the value read.  I get errors for this problem:  Warning: Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
44:  [/appsdata/home/wk211a/Projects/vrat4/minexample.R#61]
1: runApp

The second problem is that I cannot get the simple renderText message to display in the first tab.

Here is the code:

```
##### Test Example

##### Setup VRAT App

ContCurrentSideBarPanelUI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "sbpcontin",
      tabPanel(
        "Setup",
        value = "setup_Cont_Curr",
        textOutput(ns("result"))
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Verification",
        value = "verify_Cont_Curr"
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Process",
        value = "process_Cont_Curr"
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Design",
        value = "req_Cont_Curr"
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Risk Analysis",
        value = "risk_Cont_Curr",
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Guardbanding",
        value = "gb_Cont_Curr"
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Sampling",
        value = "sample_Cont_Curr"
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Decon",
        value = "decon_Cont_Curr"
      )
    )
  )
}

ContCurrentSideBarPanelServer <- function(id,appTabs,Maincount){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session){
      observe({
        output$result <- renderText({
          paste0("Here I am ", 63)
        })
     })
      
      observe({
        if (appTabs == "cont_Data" ) {
          showElement(id = "goButton")
          hideElement(id = "goButton3")
        }
      })
      x <- 93
      return(x)
    }
  )
}

VRATui <- shinyUI(
  
  ### Start Navbar Page
  
  navbarPage(
    title = "Test Tool",
    selected = "Introduction",
    fluid=TRUE,
    
    ### Start App Tab panel
    
    tabsetPanel(id = "appTabs",
                type = "pills",
                
                 ### Start the tab panel for the Data Screen
                
                tabPanel(
                  value = "cont_Data",
                  title = "Continuous Data",
                  
                  ### Start the Continuous sidebar layout
                  
                  sidebarLayout(
                    
                    ### Start the Continuous sidebar panel
                    
                    sidebarPanel(
                      id = "cndsp",
                      width = 3,
                      style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 80vh",
                      
                      h4("Analysis of Current Data"),
                      hr(style="border-color: darkblue;"),
                      
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "input.appTabs == 'cont_Data' && input.Maincont == 'currentCont'",
                        
                        ### Submit setup for analysis
                        
                        actionButton(inputId = "goButton", label = "Start Current Analysis", width = '100%'),
                        actionButton(inputId = "goButton3", label = "Update Current Analysis", width = '100%'),
                        
                        ### Sidebar Panel Tabs
                        
                        ContCurrentSideBarPanelUI("ContCurrentSideBarPanel")
                      ),
                      
                    ### End Continuous Data Analysis sidebar panel 
                    
                  ),  
                      mainPanel()
                  
                  ### End the sidebar layout
                  
                ), 
                
                ### End the Data tab panel
                
    )
    
    
  ) 
  ### End the app tabPanelSet
) 
### End the navbarPage
)

VRATserver <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  test <- ContCurrentSideBarPanelServer(id = "ContCurrentSideBarPanel",
                                        reactive(input$appTabs),
                                        Maincount = reactive(input$Maincount))
  })



shinyApp(
  ui = VRATui,
  server = VRATserver
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be easy.  I was not passing the outer parameter as reactive correctly.  It should be reactive({...}) not reactive(...).  Once corrected, then the module responded to appTabs() correctly and the if statement completed without error.  When this worked, the text was correctly entered into the sidebar tab.